# Get distinct result set in marklogic server

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I have a XML document like this.

```
  <Authors>
      <Author>
        <name>R.N Tagore</name>
        <book>Gitanjli</book>
      </Author>
      <Author>
        <name>Premchand</name>
        <book>Panch Parameshvar</book>
      </Author>
      <Author>
        <name>H.R Bacchan</name>
        <book>Madhushala</book>
      </Author>
      <Author>
        <name>Premchand</name>
        <book>Gaban</book>
      </Author>
      <Author>
        <name>Premchand</name>
        <book>Nirmala</book>
      </Author>
      <Author>
        <name>Premchand</name>
        <book>Nirmala</book>
      </Author>
  </Authors>
```

From the above XML I need distinct list of author's name.
For this I can write a query like ,

```
fn:distinct-values(cts:search(fn:doc()//pa:Author/pa:name,cts:and-query(())))
```

What the above code will do is, It will get result of Authors name and then **fn:distinct-values()** function will filter distinct Author name from that result set. For the current scenario it will work fine because data in XML only 6, But when data is very high let say 50 lac's

```
cts:search(fn:doc()//pa:Author/pa:name,cts:and-query(()))
```

the above portion of query will give **XDMP-EXPNTREECACHEFULL** Exception because we are trying to cache 50 lac's  element in memory.
So need your help to get only distinct author name by using **cts:search** or **search:search** API. I don't want to first get a result set and then extract distinct record from that result set by using **fn:distinct-values()**.
Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

This question is addressed in the middle of the Ninja tutorial off of the front page of the [MarkLogic Community website](http://community.marklogic.com), which I recommend you read.

See http://community.marklogic.com/try/ninja/page7

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quickly over a large data set by setting up a range index on `name`. Once you have that, use [cts:values()](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values).

```
cts:values(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("name")))
```

This code assumes that you use the default collation for the index.

Note that when you have a generic element name like "name", you may want to use a path index to be more precise. In this case, you might set up a path range index on Author/name, then

```
cts:values(cts:path-reference(xs:QName("Author/name")))
```

(I'm assuming you are using MarkLogic 7+; if not, you can use [cts:element-values()](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values) instead of cts:values().)